# win32 attributes are not being recognized by python 3

Tags: python, windows, process, pywin32, psutil

I have installed `psutil` and `pywin32`, and I am trying to use this code:

```
import psutil
import win32process, win32api, win32con


# Find the Chrome process
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == "chrome.exe":
        chrome_process = proc
        break

# Get the command line arguments of the Chrome process
_, _, pid, _ = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(chrome_process.handle())
handle = win32api.OpenProcess(
    win32con.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | win32con.PROCESS_VM_READ, False, pid
)
argv = win32process.GetCommandLine(handle)

# Extract the URL from the command line arguments
url = argv.split(" ")[-1]
print(url)
```

In Visual Studio Code, the attributes just appear as white text.

I get an error that says:

```
AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute 'handle'
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `chrome_process.handle()`, exactly what do you expect this to mean, and **why** do you expect it to mean that? *Why should it be possible* to use `.handle()` on this `chrome_process`? Did you try to **read the documentation**, in order to understand what functionality is provided by the `Process` class and how to use it? [Did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to use a search engine to look up the error message? What happened when you tried this?

Comment: Please also read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We [do not care](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950) about your level of experience, because it does not change the answer to questions - we will adjust the tone of answers according to the apparent difficulty of the material - and it does not help understand that question. I [edit]ed the question to show how to ask clearly and directly. However, I cannot understand what you meant by "Attributes are just white text on VSC". I think perhaps you should first make sure you understand *what "attribute" means*.

Comment: Yea, I searched it online but the error message is way too general and yes, I did read the documentation. I think it is essential to keep in mind that it's not only the .handle variable I'm having trouble with, python doesn't recognize three of them: (.GetCommandLine, .split, .handle). 

I use the psutil library to list all the processes running on the system and find the Chrome process, then use the win32process module to get the command line arguments of the process so that I can see the URLs of the websites that are being visited.

Comment: "python doesn't recognize three of them: (.GetCommandLine, .split, .handle)" Okay; why do you think it should? Can you point at the specific parts of the documentation that tell you that they should work, and what they supposedly do? (Also, standard are-the-lights-on stuff: did you check **what version** of the libraries this documentation is for? Did you check what version you have installed?)

Comment: Ok, I'm using the latest version of the libraries. Now I will show the pertinent documentation for each attribute that isn't working: 
**.split** [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) - this isn't from win32 but I just don't get why it doesn't work
**.handle** [link](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32process__GetWindowThreadProcessId_meth.html) - (I use handle as specified there, maybe I'm misunderstanding)
**.GetCommandLine** [link](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__GetCommandLine_meth.html) - same here

Answer (score 0):

The error, as the (incomplete - check [[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) text suggests, comes from this line:

```py
_, _, pid, _ = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(chrome_process.handle())
```

so it has nothing to do with *PyWin32* (*BTW*, the line has other errors too (*win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId* only returns 2 values), but let's leave that aside).

According to [[ReadTheDocs]: psutil - Process class](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#process-class), there's no method called *handle*, but there is:

> - **cmdline()**
>
> The command line this process has been called with as a list of strings. The return value is not cached because the cmdline of a process may change.

Apparently, you don't even need *PyWin32*, as your goal is achievable using solely *PSUtil*.

Example (I only display the first entries (I have many *Chrome* windows with many many tabs open), as I don't want to fill the answer with garbage):

> ```py
> >>> import psutil
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> for proc in psutil.process_iter():
> ...     if proc.name() == "chrome.exe":
> ...         print(proc.pid)
> ...         try:
> ...             print(proc.cmdline())
> ...         except PermissionError:
> ...             print("Error")
> ...
> 312
> ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe', '--type=renderer', '--lang=en-US', '--device-scale-factor=1', '--num-raster-threads=4', '--enable-main-frame-before-activation', '--renderer-client-id=169', '--time-ticks-at-unix-epoch=-1673083008231246', '--launch-time-ticks=15068979802', '--mojo-platform-channel-handle=10132', '--field-trial-handle=1988,i,5212516154784317323,8585695678623502888,131072', '/prefetch:1']
> 1464
> ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe', '--type=renderer', '--lang=en-US', '--device-scale-factor=1', '--num-raster-threads=4', '--enable-main-frame-before-activation', '--renderer-client-id=213', '--time-ticks-at-unix-epoch=-1673083008231246', '--launch-time-ticks=18739962058', '--mojo-platform-channel-handle=14864', '--field-trial-handle=1988,i,5212516154784317323,8585695678623502888,131072', '/prefetch:1']
> 1492
> ...
> ```